# Windows doesn't see gparted partition done

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, ssd, gparted

i have a pc with has dual boot of win10 and 14.04 at different ssds, recently i have seen that i spend much more time on ubuntu and made it my primary os, windows had 250gb ssd while ubuntu had 60gb, so i wanted to make a partition somewhere like 60gb for media storage and stuff and format it as ntsf, done it with gparted, however while ubuntu recognising one 180gb one 60gb storage windows sees it as 250gb storage as C://. I haven't touched bootflags and stuff but not 60gb has 14mb of smt inside there and i dunno what those are? can you help me out?? BTW windows still bootable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by tweaking a bit, forgot the disable the fastboot of windows 10 lastly, for those who wanna know it keeps the drives mounted in order to boot faster, and bamm, it's done. Tried both diskmgmt and gparted and works well. Finally i can experience true open source after quitting gaming :D